# Android Save and Write Text File with Intent, getting IOException "No content provider"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, mediastore

I get an exception when I try to write content to a file created with an Intent.

The error is an IOException error

> "No content provider:Intent {...}".

I see the file created in "My Drive", but it has no contents.

I want to output the text to a text file. This is a step on the way toward outputting data to an audio wav file.

I'm basically doing this tutorial, except I'm using Kotlin:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGD1Kr7A77Y&ab_channel=Sam%27sAndroidClassroom

The code is in an Activity file. "buttonFiles" is the button I'm adding a Click Listerner to.

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_extra)
        
        buttonFiles.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent()
                .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                .setType("text/plain")
                .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "testFileSam.txt")
                .setAction(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT)
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "text file"), 1)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            var uri = data
    
            try{
                if(uri != null) {
                    var outputStream = contentResolver.openOutputStream(Uri.parse(uri.toString()))
                    val charset = Charsets.UTF_8
                    outputStream?.write("Hello, is anybody out there!!!".toByteArray(charset))
                }

            }catch( e: IOException){
                Log.d("Debug"," IOException = " + e.message)
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Start by replacing `Uri.parse(uri.toString())` with `uri`. Then, if you still get your problem, you might want to edit your question and post the complete stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks.   It sees that as a type mismatch.  The compile error is "Type mismatch: inferred type is Intent but Uri was expected".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```kotlin
var uri = data
```

`data` is an `Intent?`.  You are assigning it to a variable named `uri`, confusing both of us.

Change that to:

```kotlin
val uri = data?.data
```

Now, `uri` will be a `Uri?`. You can use that with your `null` check. And, from there, you can use `contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri.toString())` to open the `OutputStream`.

This is also why you were running into a problem originally. You created a string representation of an `Intent`, then tried parsing that as as `Uri`, which is not going to work.

Comment: Yes, I'm still new to using Kotlin and programming on Android.   It does now execute the outputStream code, but for some reason there are no contents in the file.   I'm also curious why the file isn't overwritten.  I have several testFileSam.txt files in MyDrive.

Comment: @JohnAlway: "for some reason there are no contents in the file" -- you are not flushing and closing the stream. "I'm also curious why the file isn't overwritten. I have several testFileSam.txt files in MyDrive" -- are you sure that they all have the same name? Also, what is "MyDrive"?

Comment: @CommonWare --  On the Android emulator, I go to "Settings->Storage->SDCARD->(upper left corner menu bar) ->Files->Drive->MyDrive".   Inside that folder I see "testFileSam.txt" for each creation, all with no content.

Comment: I can get there much faster by clicking on the app "Drive" and then going to "MyDrive".

Comment: @JohnAlway: It would appear that you are storing things in Google Drive. I cannot comment on why Google Drive behaves that way.

Comment: --I've been at this for a while, and what I'm trying to do is save an audio wav file to an easily accessible shared folder.    Right now I can only save to my private app space.    My programming has been on Windows and Linux.  The file system on Android appears to more complex.    Is MediaStore the way to go? Thanks for you help. I appreciate it.

Comment: @JohnAlway: "Right now I can only save to my private app space" -- `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` will let the user save wherever the user wants. You just happen to be choosing Google Drive. You might want to experiment using your app on an actual Android device. But, if you configured your emulator with storage space, you should have an option for storing it locally, in addition to storing it on Drive. "The file system on Android appears to more complex" -- for security reasons, "easily accessible shared folder" no longer really exists on Android 11+.

Comment: @JohnAlway: "Is MediaStore the way to go?" -- that's a possibility for Android 11+, where you use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` on Android 10 and older. [This sample Kotlin app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/tree/vFINAL/ConferenceVideos) demonstrates downloading a video and storing it using `MediaStore` or `Environment`, depending on Android version.